# WCF - Generating and consuming WSDL using SoapUI + Error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, soapui

Hello developers I'm new in WCF in generating wsdl and consuming it using SoapUI. I have some questions:

The first thing, I have developed string datamember but I designed as mandatory datatype using IsRequired=true, so in the generated wsdl these datatypes are exposed as mandatory with the dissapearing of minOcurr = 0, but there still the field nillable=true (the reason is that string datatypes implements string.empty as a default behaviour), so it has no corresponding with mandatory, but nill=true means that I can pass null value throught these fields. Do u know how to fix it?

The second thing is similar as the first, but in this case is with the DataContract, when I load my wsdl in SoapUI I observe that it put in my data format the tag Optional above all datacontract, it means that it can be erased, but in my case these datacontract are mandatory, so when I observe in my wsdl on these datacontract exist the FU.... tag nullable=true, so raise out a similar question that is: Do u know how to fix it?

And finally, I have a field that is char datatype, so in my SoapUI when I consume a webservice sending data I can pass a letter as a char so the only solution is sending its ascii character, eg: if I wanna pass the letter 'J', I need to put 74, so I want to know a way to implement that I can pass the real letter throught the SoapUI.

Comment: As an alternative, you can try to use Validations. Enterprise Library has a Validation component which can be integrated with wcf. Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648939.aspx

Comment: The question is that I supposed that this way to declarate should be into the way of declaring in WCF... so if there is not possible in WCF, it means that WCF is incomplete yet